# Invisible text for excerpt while editing a tag wiki

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tag-wiki

While editing a tag wiki on Stack Exchange site [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/about), I noticed that the excerpt is partly obscured by the right-hand side panel. I don't know if this is specific to Cross Validated, but I haven't seen it on the [SOFU](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354) sites. It this a bug on the Stack Exchange side?

[image: Screenshot from editing the tag wiki "probit" on Stack Exchange site Cross Validated.]

Platform: Firefox 22.0 with [NoScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript) on Windows.

Comment: I see this on Chrome as well. Just on CrossValidated though.

Comment: I [saw this too](http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194/text-box-overflows-into-sidebar) on RE and other sites.

Comment: @AsheeshR: what sites show this? That's interesting to know, because I figured this was a CV-only issue. Since RE is a beta site it uses the default beta styles, and I cannot reproduce this on any other beta.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Don't remember at the moment. I will update if I see it again. Here's a [more recent instance](http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/254/189) of it on RE.

Comment: Apparently, the global profile doesnt retain review history [beyond 100 reviews](http://stackexchange.com/users/1609527/asheeshr?tab=activity).

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Win 7, FF 24.0 (since that came out, 22.0 is no longer a supported version in terms of UI glitches).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CrossValidated CSS uses a fixed size for textareas:

```
textarea{
    font-family: Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, serif;
    border:1px solid #999;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

while the rest of the network uses `font-size: 90%` instead; the font-size here pushes this specific textarea too wide and causes the overlap.

A more specific width constraint is needed here to compensate for that. The WMD editor is constrained to `width: 660px;` and thus remains visible.

This appears to be a CV-only bug.